# How to scrape the details after click for every event

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape the header of every popup for every match on https://www.wagertalk.com/odds

So, I want to click on every event at where Open is and popup will appear, where I want to scrape the header, like in the picture that would be College football.
I want to do it for every match but my scraper stops after doing it for first match.

[image]

my code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
#from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
url = 'https://www.wagertalk.com/odds'
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
# row.find_elements("css selector",'.time-started')
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
for row in driver.find_elements("css selector",'tr[id^="g"]'):
    

    books = row.find_elements("css selector",'.book')
    for b in books:
        print('--- popup ---')

        # open .popupDiv
        b.click()
        
        time.sleep(1)
        # ... scrape table from .popupDiv ...
        tds = driver.find_elements("css selector",'.popupDiv th.header')
        print(tds[0].text)
        
        # close .popupDiv
        driver.find_elements("css selector"'.popupDiv button').click()

driver.quit()
```

After I run the code I will receive the first match but then the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.71)
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x000000010ad9ff38 chromedriver + 4910904
1   chromedriver                        0x000000010ad1fa03 chromedriver + 4385283
2   chromedriver                        0x000000010a964747 chromedriver + 472903
3   chromedriver                        0x000000010a9a8d5d chromedriver + 752989
4   chromedriver                        0x000000010a9a95a1 chromedriver + 755105
5   chromedriver                        0x000000010a9eced1 chromedriver + 1031889
6   chromedriver                        0x000000010a9cf13d chromedriver + 909629
7   chromedriver                        0x000000010a9ea28e chromedriver + 1020558
8   chromedriver                        0x000000010a9ceee3 chromedriver + 909027
9   chromedriver                        0x000000010a99930c chromedriver + 688908
10  chromedriver                        0x000000010a99a88e chromedriver + 694414
11  chromedriver                        0x000000010ad6d1de chromedriver + 4702686
12  chromedriver                        0x000000010ad71b19 chromedriver + 4721433
13  chromedriver                        0x000000010ad7928e chromedriver + 4752014
14  chromedriver                        0x000000010ad7291a chromedriver + 4725018
15  chromedriver                        0x000000010ad46b02 chromedriver + 4545282
16  chromedriver                        0x000000010ad91888 chromedriver + 4851848
17  chromedriver                        0x000000010ad91a05 chromedriver + 4852229
18  chromedriver                        0x000000010ada7e5f chromedriver + 4943455
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff203598fc _pthread_start + 224
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff20355443 thread_start + 15
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Comma is missing in the close .popupDiv.